# DotNetOpenAuth in MVC4 - Yahoo doesn't work

Tags: oauth, visual-studio-2012, dotnetopenauth, yahoo

I am migrating my existing project from MVC3 to MVC4.  In MVC3 I used Microsoft Azure's Access Control Service (ACS) for getting user identity.  I would like to use DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet that comes with VS2012 to replace the old method, and I am studying this with the sample website that VS2012 created when you start a new 'Internet Application' project.

I followed the tutorial and made the necessary changes in AuthConfig.cs, trying to enable using facebook & google & yahoo to authenticate.  The facebook works ok.  Both Google and yahoo don't work, and result.IsSuccessful is always false in the function ExternalLoginCallback().

I did some google search and found this site: https://github.com/mj1856/DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2.  I followed this site and finally got google work.

However, I am still stuck with the yahoo problem.  I wonder if there is any similar solution for yahoo like google.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I didn't see this sooner.  Glad you like my [Google OAuth2](https://github.com/mj1856/DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2) adapter.  I wrote one for [Facebook](https://github.com/mj1856/DotNetOpenAuth.FacebookOAuth2) also.

I checked, but I couldn't find any support from Yahoo for OAuth2.  They appear to support only OpenID or OAuth 1.  You might as well us the OpenID client that ships with OAuthWebSecurity in MVC4.

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterYahooClient();
```

If anyone know of Yahoo OAuth2 support, please let me know.  Thanks.